# Continuous Integration for personal use

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

Suppose I work in a team and would like to test my code before committing/pushing it to the trunk/master. So, I need a simple *continuous integration* server to:

- build the application locally
- start it and run integration tests
- save a report

I would like it to run in both Windows/Linux.

I wouldn't like to use `Jenkins` (or any other *real* continuous integration server) for that purpose. I would prefer a more *lightweight* solution. I can develop a simple Java/Groovy app. but I would prefer an *off-the-shelf* solution.

What would you suggest ?

Comment: Jenkins is *very* easy to install, configure, and use.  And it's generally very good at its job.  Why wouldn't you want to use it?

Comment: Thanks, Oli. I will check Jenkins.

Comment: If you're using windows the tray tracker will notify you when a Jenkins build has failed, really useful. http://code.google.com/p/hudson-tray-tracker/ You could also enhance your local Jenkins setup by automating the code push as a post build action. If you build runs and tests locally it automatically gets pushed!

Answer (score 2):

Automated build system (Maven, Ant, Gradle etc) can work as a CI. You can run it from command line or periodically from cron / task scheduler. Maven can generate a full HTML report with its "site" command.

```
mvn site
```

Or if you prefer a GUI, then use Jenkins. You can fire it up from the command line with a simple

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

There is no need to install anything